# retrosynthesis gamma-hydroxy ketone

Tags: green-chemistry, retrosynthesis

One of the sections about retrosynthesis in Warren's book addresses how to access $\gamma$-hydroxy carbonyl compounds like **ZM181**.  This is again one of the examples to advice the reader to check the results for plausibility: while epoxides *often may* be a suitable building block, *here*, the intermediate would react further with the ester present to yield a lactone (second line) instead:

[image]

In the edition accessible to mine, Warren apparently does not detail out if an alternative approach with chloro- or bromoethanol (third line) to yield **ZM181** were viable.

Question: Would be the approach of the third line, chloroethanol and ethyl acetoacetate to yield **ZM181**, still viable *outside* academia, too?

I'm aware the intramolecular transesterification to yield a five-membered cycle needs to be considered as a possible product for both approaches.  On the other hand, I think either route could be favoured by choice of the reaction conditions, i.e.

- *complete single deprotonation* of ethyl acetylacetonate in dry THF by one equivalent $\ce{NaH}$ (not two), then followed by the addition of the expoxide may ease the formation of the lactone. The reasoning of $\ce{NaH}$ is to ensure *all* of the starting material is deprotonated once with the irreversible escape of $\ce{H2}$. Or,
- the *partial*, equilibrium based deprotonation of the $\beta$-dicarbonyl compound by $\ce{K2CO3}$ in a mixture of THF/water, in presence of the bromo ethanol already present, might reduce the concentration of alcoholate and thus lower chances of the formation of the lactone.  This line of thought accounts for the different $pK_a$ of the reagents present, e.g., water could protonate free alcoholate, too.

Reference: Stuart Warren *Organische Retrosynthese*, Teubner, Stuttgart 1997.

Comment: I don’t think the second and third lines are realistically different - you’d need a base present in both so if the lactone is favourable , it would form in both cases. 

Practically, depending on what the next step in the synthesis is, the lactone might be fine (eg can still add a nucleophile in, or reduce it down)

Comment: Also the 1,3-dicarbonyl likely exists (to a large extent) as the enolised form, which may protect the lactone from forming immediately after the addition.

Comment: The only advantage I see of the bromoethanol route is that you could put a protecting group on the -OH and prevent lactone formation that way

Comment: For a moment, I thought running the reaction of the second line in _dry THF_ would indeed yield the lactone. Contrasting to this -- given the different pKa of the beta-dicarbonyl compound and of an alcohol -- I think now, running the reaction of the third line with $\ce{K2CO3}$ in a _mixture of water and THF_ could reduce a the concentration of free alcoholate to trigger the intramolecular transesterification.  But still it could be an uphill battle (already because intramolecular reactions are favoured over intermolecular ones, and the formation of a cycle of five atoms, etc.).

Comment: What is the [tag:green-chemistry] aspect of this? The bromide looks hazardous enough to me to kick this out of the category.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Maybe today there is an other nucleofuge / other C2 precursor (halogen free) which gained much popularity.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I think it's a viable question well asked. I just don't see how the tags fit. The question is essentially about a synthesis; not retrosynthesis, because that part was already done. And forgive me, but I don't see any aspect of green chemistry mentioned here. I'd use completely different tags, but I wanted to ask, maybe you just would like to clarify this.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン My interpretation of your comment is that you suggest to retract the retrocynthesis tag (regardless if this inspired the question) an a reformulation.  Perhaps in lines of this: «Aiming for **ZM181**, oxirane is not suitable because the intermediate forms a lactone (second line) if the reaction takes place in dry THF.  Possibly chloro ethanol / bromo ethanol could yield the desired product under equilibrium conditions of $\ce{K2CO3}$ and a mixture of THF/water (third line). Question: is there a halogen-free C2 precursor leading to the target?»